# How to go through list looking whether first letter in each string is upper case? (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function so that it can check to see if the first letter in each string in a list is uppercase.

```
def capital(str_list):
    for n in str_list:
        if n[0].isupper():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

If I have a list, it's only checking the first word. How do I check if the first letter of each word in the list is uppercase or not?

Comment: the reason why your function only checks the first word in the list is because you have a `return` statement within your `for loop` in the `if else` statement. as soon as a python function finds a `return` statement in it and it gets executed, in your case, it finishes checking the first word, it exits the function.

Answer (score 4):

```
[s.istitle() for s in str_list]
```

or

```
[s[0].isupper() for s in str_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Return `False` immediately when you stumble upon a non-uppercase letter and return `True` only after you've checked each element:

```
def capital(str_list):
    for n in str_list:
        if not n[0].isupper():
            return False 
    return True
```

You may also consider a more compact solution using `all`:

```
def capital(str_list): return all(i[0].isupper() for i in str_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `True` if you find a word that starts with upper case, you need to return `False` when one word doesn't start with upper case. After completing the loop just return `True` because now all your word starts with upper case.

```
def capital(str_list):
    for n in str_list:
        if not n[0].isupper():
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

More pythonic way:

```
def capital(str_list):
    return all(n[0].isupper() for n in str_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find python's builtin `any()` and `all()` functions useful: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

```
def capital(str_list):
    return all(n[0].isupper() for n in str_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in my comment on your question, the reason for your function to only check for the first word in the list is due to the `return` statement, ie. as soon as a function gets its `return` statement executed, the execution of the function finishes.

Another way to do what you want to accomplish is via `map` and a `lambda` function, which can easily be customised in case you want to do something else later on.

```
str_list = ['Apple', 'berry', 'Watermelon', 'Bananas']

def capital(str_list):
    return list(map(lambda x: x[0].isupper(), str_list))

capital(str_list)
```

Output

```
[True, False, True, True]
```